# Angular 6: How do return data from observable?

Tags: angular

What I am trying to do is use `isAuth` function to retrieve data from backend and make that function return that data. Then when I call that function data gets returned into variable and I can use that data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService implements CanActivate  {
    constructor( private http: HttpClient, private router: Router ) { }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        var isAuth = this.isAuth()
        console.log(isAuth);

    }

    isAuth(){
        let obs = this.http.get('server/page/auth');
        obs.subscribe((res) => { return res});
    }   

}
```

When I console log isAuth, i get `undefined`. As I understand that is because it's not in async. In node.js you basically would trow `await` in front of the function and that would do the trick. How do I do that in here? How to I return data from `isAuth` into variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the observable from `isAuth` and subscribe it from `canActivate` function

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     this.isAuth().subscribe((res) => { console.log(res);});

}

isAuth(){
    return this.http.get('server/page/auth'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isAuth` function has no return value. You subscribe to the HTTP request but you do not actually do anything with it.

```
obs.subscribe((res) => { return res });
```

`return res` returns from the inner, anonymous function. It does not return from `isAuth`!

The Angular Docs:

```
interface CanActivate {
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

So there are many ways to do this. Anyhow, the `canActivate` function will have to return an Observable that emits a boolean, a Promise that resolves to a boolean, or a boolean primitive. You **cannot** return a subscription. If you're using Observables you can try something like this:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isAuth();
}

isAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get('server/page/auth').map(res => res.message === 'success');

    // You are returning the Observable here
    // Do use 'map' and other rxjs stream operators, do not use subscribe!!! 
    // Using subscribe will change your return value to 'Subscription', not 'Observable'!!
}
```

You can check out the RxJS docs on Observables, observers, subscription and subscribers. Good luck